# Multiple cell value change to trigger macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have different set of values in cells G3:G4 and D15:D10000 in a single sheet. I want run two separate codes when G columns or D columns are changed. How I can identify which set of columns are changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

out this in your worksheet code pane

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G3:G4")) Is Nothing Then        
        'code when some cell in range "G3:G4" is changed
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D15:D10000")) Is Nothing Then
        'code when some cell in range "D15:D10000" is changed
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the code below in your relevant worksheet, in the `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WatchRange                  As Range
Dim IntersectRange              As Range

Set WatchRange = Application.Union(Range("G3:G4"), Range("D15:D10000"))
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 4 ' column D
            Call A

        Case 7 ' column G
            Call B

    End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Below are examples of `Sub A` and `Sub B`:

```
Sub A()

MsgBox "Running Sub A"

End Sub


Sub B()

MsgBox "Running Sub B"

End Sub
```